# Exception while copying data using MLCP

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am trying to copy 1 million documents from one database to another database using MLCP but I am getting following Exception.

```
19/08/30 11:48:08 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: RuntimeException reading /integration/test/88398921012548 :java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not buffer value as string
```

I am not sure about the reason of this exception.

Please guide me to understand the reason.

**MLCP with all the options that i used**

```
mlcp copy -mode local -input_host 192.168.1.46 -input_port 9000 -input_username admin -input_password admin -input_database test  -output_host localhost -output_port 8000 -output_username admin -output_password admin -output_database test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MLCP tends to run multiple threads in parallel, but that could cause source or target system to run out of resources. Also, you are running MLCP on the same host as the target database, they might compete for resources as well. It is probably best to see what happens if you pace down MLCP using `-thread_count 1`. From there you can scale up again.

Also keep an eye on MLCP memory consumption, you might need to give it more memory using JVM_OPTS. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54685758/918496

HTH!