# Exception while copy database using MLCP copy command

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, mlcp

I am trying to copy 1.5TB size database from one database to another database using MLCP But I am getting the exception

**Instance size r5.4xlarge**

**MLCP Command**

> mlcp.bat copy -mode local -input_host localhost -input_port 8003 -input_username admin -input_password xxxx -output_host xx.xx.xx.xxx -output_port 8003 -output_username admin -output_password xxxx

**Exception**

> 23/09/14 00:01:14 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: RuntimeException read
> ing /mla/searchCopy/expanded/BIB5211557.xml :java.lang.RuntimeException: **Could not buffer value as string**
> 23/09/14 00:01:14 INFO contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: host name: localhost
> 23/09/14 00:01:15 INFO contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: Retrying connect

> 2023-09-13 23:23:22.792 SEVERE [34] (StreamingResultSequence.next):
> IOException instantiating ResultItem 6688: Error parsing HTTP headers:
> Premature EOF, partia l header line read: 'X-URI: /validati'
> java.io.IOException: Error parsing HTTP headers: Premature EOF,
> partial header line read: 'X-URI: /validati'
> com.marklogic.http.HttpHeaders.parsePlainHeaders(HttpHeaders.java:321)
> com.marklogic.http.MultipartBuffer.next(MultipartBuffer.java:103)
> com.marklogic.xcc.impl.AbstractResultSequence.instantiateResultItem(Abst
> ractResultSequence.java:132)
> com.marklogic.xcc.impl.StreamingResultSequence.next(StreamingResultSeque
> nce.java:147)
> com.marklogic.xcc.impl.StreamingResultSequence.next(StreamingResultSeque
> nce.java:166)
> com.marklogic.contentpump.DatabaseContentReader.nextKeyValue(DatabaseCon
> tentReader.java:520)
> com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner$TrackingRecordReader.nextKeyVal
> ue(LocalJobRunner.java:431)
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextI
> mpl.java:80)
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(W
> rappedMapper.java:91)
> com.marklogic.contentpump.BaseMapper.run(BaseMapper.java:66)
> com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner$LocalMapTask.call(LocalJobRunne
> r.java:343)
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Looks like the connection was dropped. Check the ErrorLog.txt to see if the server restarted or if you see other errors. If you continue to have errors, I suggest filing a support ticket.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748160/14419